# Critical velocity of a fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, viscosity

**Critical velocity($v$)** of a fluid is given by
$v = \frac{Rr}{\rho\eta}$
where,

$R \rightarrow$ Reynolds number

$r \rightarrow$ Radius of tube

$\rho \rightarrow$ Density of fluid

$\eta \rightarrow$ Coefficient of viscosity

$d \rightarrow$ Diameter or characteristic length

But when we look at the formula for Reynold's Number, we see $R = \frac{\rho vd}{\eta}$

Could anyone explain why both of them are different and how these both are derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \rightarrow$ Area of cross section of tube

$v \rightarrow$ Velocity of fluid flow in tube

$\rho \rightarrow$ Density of fluid in tube

$d \rightarrow$ Diameter or characteristic length

$\eta \rightarrow$ Coefficient of viscosity

$R_n \rightarrow$ Reynolds number

Mass of fluid flowing per second = $\mu$ = $\rho Av$

Inertial force = Force due to change in momentum = $\Delta l$= $\mu \cdot v$ = $\rho Av^2$

Viscous force = $F$ = $\eta \frac{Av}{d}$

$R_n = \frac{\Delta l}{F} = \frac{\rho A v^2}{\eta \frac{Av}{r}} = \frac{\rho A v^2 r}{\eta A v} = \frac{\rho vd}{\eta}$

Here we can see that $R_n \propto v$

It has been experimentally confirmed that laminar flow occurs when $R_n < 2300$  and turbulent flow occurs when $R_n > 3500$.

now at the critical value of $R_n$ when it is at the transition point between laminar and turbulent flow, lets say $R_c$, the velocity of the fluid would be called its critical velocity $v_c$

$v_c = \frac{R_c d}{\rho \eta}$